# Python trigger function wndProc (win32api)

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi

I'm working on a python application, I want trigger my a function when a window apps like "FileZila" resize or change size.

I don't know why but, the "MyWndProc" is not triggered..

The display is:

```
resolution: 
width : 1366 
height : 768
328924  # print(hwnd)
```

I have this sample :

```
hwnd = -1;
oldWndProc = False;

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Entry(root)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.title("test REZize trigger")
root.geometry("200x200")

app = tk.Frame(root)
app.grid()
btn_start = tk.Button(app, text="Start Scan", command=start)
btn_stop = tk.Button(app, text="Stop", command=stop)
app_text = tk.Entry(app, text="")
war_label = tk.Label(app, text="", fg="red",font = "Times")
info_label = tk.Label(app, text="", fg="blue",font = "Times")

btn_start.grid()
btn_stop.grid()
app_text.grid()
war_label.grid()
info_label.grid()



def start():
    """Enable scanning by setting the global flag to True."""
    global running
    if(running == False):
        running = True
        startbot(); 

def MyWndProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam):
    global oldWndProc;
    # Display what we've got.
    print ("PRINT MyWndProc")

    if msg == win32con.WM_SIZE:
        print("RESIZE STUFF")
        win32api.SetWindowLong(hwnd,
                               win32con.GWL_WNDPROC,
                               oldWndProc)
    if msg == win32con.WM_SIZING:
        print("RESIZING STUFF")
    return win32gui.CallWindowProc(oldWndProc,
        hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam)


def startbot():
    global hwnd,oldWndProc;
    bug = False
    width = height = 0;
    width = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(0)
    height = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(1)
    print("resolution: ")
    print("width : " + str(width) + " \nheight : " + str(height))

    msg = "";

    hwnd = get_window_hwnd("FileZilla")
    print(hwnd);
    oldWndProc = win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd,win32con.GWL_WNDPROC,MyWndProc)
    while(bug == False):
        if(hwnd != -1 or hwnd != False):
            #do something
            info_label.config(text=msg);
        stop()
        bug = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root.mainloop()
```

Any idea??

Based on [This tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: If the `filezilla` window is not originating from your process, you can't do that with `SetWindowLong()`. This is explicitly stated in the help for this API for `GWL_WNDPROC`: `You cannot change this attribute if the window does not belong to the same process as the calling thread`. Take a look at `SetWindowsHookEx()` instead.

Comment: oh.. I see. So with this way.. I need to create a dll into the `filezilla` and trying to to something? So I'm not able to hook `wm_size` or `wm_sizing` to a function in my software to edit a variable example `is_resizing = True`? I need to create a `DLL` to with a function to apply directly in the `filezilla software` and not mine? Its right?